# preposition choice:　"reckon with" or "reckon on" in British English

Tags: prepositions, phrases

Does the choice of "on" or "with" make any difference in the following?

> I didn't think that there would be a traffic jam, and didn't plan extra time in the journey. I didn't reckon **on**/**with** there being a traffic jam.

I'd appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to Merriam Webster dictionary, **'reckon on'** means *'to expect (something) to happen : to plan on (something)'*.

According to Macmillan dictionary, **'reckon with'** means *'to consider something important when you are making plans and so be prepared for it'*.

As per these definitions, in your sentence either 'on' or 'with' is possible with difference in meaning :

> *'I didn't reckon **on** there being a traffic jam.'*

It means I didn't expect a traffic jam to happen there.

> *'I didn't reckon **with** there being a traffic jam.'*

It means I didn't consider the traffic jam to be something important, and so I didn't make any plan for it or I was not prepared for it.